# Show that $ \mathbf{f(x)}=\mathbf{xe^x} $ is integrable on $\mathbf{[0,1]}$ and find the value of $ \int_0^1 xe^x \,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I can prove that  $$ \mathbf{f(x)}=\mathbf{xe^x} $$ is integrable on $\mathbf{[0,1]}$ by using the theorem, f a real function defined and bounded on [a,b].Then f is integrable on [a,b] $\iff$  $\forall$ $\epsilon$ $\gt$ 0, $\exists$ P $\in$ $\mathscr{P}$[a,b] such that U(f,P)- L(f,P) $\lt$ $\epsilon$ .

But i want to prove this using this proposition that , f a real function defined and bounded on [a,b].Then f is integrable and $$ \int_a^b f(x) \,dx = l $$ $\iff$ $\exists$ a sequence (P$_n$) of partitions of [a,b] such that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ L(f,P$_n$)=$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ U(f,P$_n$)=$l$ .

Help me to find a sequence of partitions of [0,1] such that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ L(xe$^x$,P$_n$)=$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ U(xe$^x$,P$_n$)=$1$ .

Comment: **Any** sequence of partitions will work, provided that the lengths of the subintervals tend toward zero.

Comment: can you please type an answer so that id be clearer . Than u :)

Comment: What do you get when your partition is equally spaced with $n$ intervals?  What property of $e$ will you use?

Comment: @GEdgar its not clear.Can you explain it a bit more. I cannot show that the limit goes to 1 .

Comment: I would not solve this problem using partitions.  If your instructor told you to do it that way, maybe ask him for help.  In particular: to show the limit is $1$ you need some property of the number $e$.

Comment: Can you tell me whats the property of e that i should use to show the limit is 1.?

Answer (score 2):

A start.

The function $x e^x$ is increasing on $[0,1]$, we will need this to compute maximum and minimum on an interval.

Take partitionion $P_n$ to be
$$
0, \frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\dots,\frac{n-1}{n},\frac{n}{n}
$$
Interval number $k$ is
$$
\left[\frac{k-1}{n}\;, \;\frac{k}{n}\right],
$$
 where $k=1,2,3,\dots,n$.  The length of the interval is $1/n$.  On interval number $k$, the maximum of the function is
$$
f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = \frac{k}{n}\;e^{k/n}
$$
and the minimum is
$$
f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right) = \frac{k-1}{n}e^{(k-1)/n}
$$
Next: can you compute the upper and lower sums for this partition?